# why my js variable not finding the php variable properly

Tags: javascript

I am reading a text file . and then splitting it into by 100 words in an array named "$arrpg"  and then in my js code while i am loading it to js variable , the var is unable to get the array values properly.  if you don't mind please see  a link where i uploaded it for test purpose ([link](http://leiame.patio.com.br/read/readf/muricoca))

here my input text file is "

> A MUSICISTA E O GUERREIRO
>   À noite, deitado, no escuro, não tenho forças para evitar o concerto da virtuose muriçoca. Ela vem dali até aqui na velocidade do som. Procuro capturá-la com a mão, ela -- vivace -- ...........................so many more

"

my js code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">


$(document).ready(function() {




    var ind=0;
   var tempv1;
   var tempv2;


    var pages=<?php echo json_encode((int)($page_num));?>;

    var jsarr= <?php echo json_encode($arrpg); ?>;


    var wmap=<?php 

    echo json_encode($word_map); ?>;
    var myurl=<?php echo json_encode($my_link.'write_comment/'.$file_name.'/'.$total_word.'/');?>











     $('.more').each(function() {



        pages++;

           $(this).html(jsarr[ind]);

        tempv2= ' <a class="link2" href="'+myurl+wmap[0]  + '">';


        if(pages!==1)
        {

            tempv1='<span>.... <a href=""class="link1">Read more</a></span>';
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Stop reading</a>';
            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);
            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }
        else
        {


            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Please a feedback</a>';

            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }





            scroll();









        });   


    $(".link1").click(function(){


        ind++;


        $('div.more').append(jsarr[ind]);



        tempv2= '<a class="link2" href="'+myurl+wmap[ind]  + '">';

        if(ind<(pages-1) )
        {
            tempv1='<span>.... <a href=""class="link1">Read more</a></span>';
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Stop reading</a>';


            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);
            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);

        }
        else 
        {
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Please a feedback</a>';

            tempv1='';
            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);







            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }



        scroll();

        return false;
    });
});



            function scroll(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ft").offset().top
  }, 0);
}



</script>
```

in this code declaration of jsarr can't get the values properly. seeing the link u will realize more. please help.

after 1st edit

```
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">


$(document).ready(function() {




    var ind=0;
   var tempv1;
   var tempv2;


    var pages=5;

    var jsarr= [" A MUSICISTA E O GUERREIRO\r\n"," a m"," agudo violino. Cubro a\\norelha, sinto calor, descubro a orelha, escuto a muri"," da habilidosa\\ninstrumentista. Na manh"," palmas de\\nminhas m"," morta, rubronegra\\n-- na plan"];
    alert(jsarr);

    var wmap=[30,60,90,120,150,175];
    var myurl="http:\/\/leiame.patio.com.br\/read\/write_comment\/muricoca\/175\/"  











     $('.more').each(function() {



        pages++;

           $(this).html(jsarr[0]);

        tempv2= ' <a class="link2" href="'+myurl+wmap[0]  + '">';


        if(pages!==1)
        {

            tempv1='<span>.... <a href=""class="link1">Read more</a></span>';
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Stop reading</a>';
            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);
            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }
        else
        {


            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Please a feedback</a>';

            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }





            scroll();









        });   


    $(".link1").click(function(){


        ind++;


        $('div.more').append(jsarr[ind]);



        tempv2= '<a class="link2" href="'+myurl+wmap[ind]  + '">';

        if(ind<(pages-1) )
        {
            tempv1='<span>.... <a href=""class="link1">Read more</a></span>';
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Stop reading</a>';


            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);
            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);

        }
        else 
        {
            tempv2='<br><br>'+tempv2+'Please a feedback</a>';

            tempv1='';
            $('div.link1').html(tempv1);







            $('div.link2').html(tempv2);


        }



        scroll();

        return false;
    });
});



            function scroll(){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#ft").offset().top
  }, 0);
}



</script>`
```

Comment: Can you show the output of the code in HTML? What is given to the `var wmap`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i have added what u told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_encode has some trouble with non utf8 chars.

the string parsing within json encode is then  stopped at the first non utf8 char found.

so i would suggest:

utf8_encode each value in $arrpg before submitting to json_encode.

Comment: <?php for($i=0;$i<count($arrpg);$i++){$arrpg[$i]=utf8_encode($arrpg[$i]);} ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
function fix_encoding (&$item, $key)
{
    $item = utf8_encode ($item);
}

array_walk_recursive ($arrpg, 'fix_encoding');
```